# How precisely do I need to post close to 7:00 (somewhere) to get hero of time?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2017

Timezones... are complicated. We have full hour offsets, half hour offsets...

And time keeping isn't always accurate. So does the Hero Of Time hat assume full or half hour offsets (or literally any timezone) and how close to 7:00 at somewhere do I have to post for my hat?

Comment: And what are the other requirements?  Presumably it has to be upvoted.  What about open?  I had what I thought was a qualifying question that turned out to be a dupe, and haven't gotten the hat.  (It was definitely 7PM on the US west coast, though.)

Comment: I think upvoted and open are implicitly required. I also might have posted this at noon so I'd get it if other criteria was met ;p

Comment: So, has to stay open until the hat-check runs, I guess -- I'm assuming they don't revoke hats.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't mind an answer - and this is a real, temporaily relevant question

Comment: Oh I assumed your question was real, and I just answered.  I was lamenting that *my* carefully-timed question was also real, but a non-obvious dupe.  Oh well; the season is young.

Comment: I asked a question when it was 7PM and 42 seconds in Japan (it was 11AM and 42 seconds in my time zone), and I didn't get the hat. Maybe because the question was a duplicate, but it also got an upvote before it was closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Winter Bash 2015 included **It's Always 5 O'Clock Somewhere**.  According to the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/06/winter-bash-2015-hats-off/), it was awarded for asking a question at exactly 5:01 in any time zone.  "Exactly" meant within that minute on the timestamp, so you had 60 seconds.  But you had those 60 seconds every hour and a few other times besides.

You can use [this list of time zones with UTC offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) to work out all the not-on-the-hour choices.  There are a few time zones with half-hour offsets, and a few with 45-minute offsets.  You should be able to find some times that work with your schedule.

You earned the hat for this question, which you posted at 04:00:16Z.  If you want to science the range I guess you'll need to try other sites.

Comment: Confirmed. I posted a question at 00:01 GMT but didn't get the hat. So, it should be posted when the clock is x:00. We only have 60 seconds.